# How do I setup cygwin 1.7 on a Windows 2000 machine

Tags: cygwin, windows-2000

I have a box running Win2k to support a few legacy applications that can't be migrated forward at this point that I'd like to manage for most part with Cygwin.

However, the [current](https://www.cygwin.com/) Cygwin installer requires Windows XP 3.  The [installer referenced](http://www.fruitbat.org/Cygwin/#cygwintimemachine) by the good folks at at Cygwin Time Machine runs just fine, but when I attempt to configure any suggested circa release area and proceed, the installer errors out attempting to download **setup-2.bz2.sig** and **setup-2.ini.sig**.

The circa release area I'm attempting to use is [here](ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa-2/2009/12/22/013115/index.html).

Directory listing is not enabled, so really can't tell you anything more than the fact that **setup-2.ini** and **setup-2.bz2** are there, but their signatures are not.  Seems to be the case for a random sample of other releases listed [here](ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa-2/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cygwin Time Machine](http://www.fruitbat.org/Cygwin/#cygwintimemachine) was enormously helpful in resolving this issue.  Essentially, my woes were caused by

1. attempting to draw in packages from the Cygwin's 1.7 "development" branch (the **setup-2.*** errors).
2. using a setup installer too fresh for my purposes.

Digging around the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org), I found the last installation page update in which Windows 2000 ([1 June 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130601134542/http://www.cygwin.com/)) still supported and downloaded the cached installer ([link to setup.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20130601134542/http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)).

Cygwin Time Machine suggested these alternatives:

1. ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/snapshots/setup-2.602.exe
2. ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/snapshots/setup-2.573.2.3.exe
3. ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/snapshots/setup-2.523.exe

However, the 1 Jun 2013 installer ([link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130601134542/http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)) is considerably newer, can make use of [a fresher repository](ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2013/06/04/121035/index.html) (I'm able to install python 2.7.3 rather than 2.5.2), and has the nice filter feature we're used to in more modern installers.

Finally, Fruitbats **does not** archive the signatures for the setup package lists. You run at your own risk.

To ignore signatures, run the setup installer with an **-X** flag, i.e.:

```
c:\...> setup.exe -X
```

That about wraps it up.  I have a mid-2013 Cygwin 1.7 installed on Win2k Advanced Server SP4.